# Multiple tabhosts or buttons

Tags: android

I'm currently developing app for one shop as design came together i stumbled upon a problem. There is one main `activity` which has five tabs on top and also in one of those top tabs there are two tabs on the bottom to switch between `activity's` in that main(top) tab. 
   As i started to develop `UI` i put another tab host at the bottom (bad idea, beacose it somehow corrupts design of top tabs(top tab background is streched)).

So the question is What would be the best way to make 3 activity's fit and work in one tab?
Should i use `buttons` or another `tabhost` or some other `widget`?

Comment: you might get better answers here: http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in my project then I used used 3 different layouts(Xml) which I inflate for button's click in same activty using layout inflator.
(Make one visible while other two layout gone.It will look like 3 different activities)